# Is there a way to preserve the documents folder when installing a new IPA from an ad-hoc deployment?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ipa, ad-hoc-distribution

The client wants to preserve the document sandbox when I release an updated IPA using ad-hoc deployment.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Just copy the documents from the sandbox into the new application folder.

If there are specific documents that the end-user will always want to have, consider building them into your project.

Comment: But the new IPA overwrites the documents folder on install, how would I copy them?

Comment: Copy the documents to a safe place, install the new IPA, then copy the documents back into the folder.